# Convex optimization dual problem solution

Tags: convex-optimization

In the below solution, should “choose y = -tv_i” read “…y = tv_i”? If not, please explain the rest of the reasoning - it seems to me that as t-> +inf the second term grows large positive along with the first term

[image]

Comment: Correct, should be $t v_i$. Also, there are many possible duals, the above is just one,.